# Matlab Accessing Multi .NET Assembly

Tags: .net, matlab

I have an assembly 'A' with class 'MyClass' which uses classes from another assembly 'B'. 
In my C# solution, I've done the referencing to B within VS2010, and this seems to be giving me the problems in Matlab as I'm getting the following message.

Message: Could not load file or assembly 'A.MyClass, Version=2.1.1.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
Source: A.MyClass

Is there any way around this or am I missing something obvious? 
(Commands used were Net.AddAssembly and Import (on both A and B), then instantiating object and calling a method).

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, found the problem.
One of the dependent classes wouldn't be loaded properly as it doesn't have a namespace.